# Trace inequality on positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, positive-definite

My question is the following:

> Suppose that $A, B$ are symmetric positive definite real matrices.
> Is it true that
> $$
> \mathrm{trace}\big((A+B)^{-1}\big)\geq \frac{1}{2} \min\Big\{\mathrm{trace}(A^{-1}), \mathrm{trace}(B^{-1})\Big\}
> $$

---

**Some comments**:

- This is clearly true in the scalar case:
  $$
  \frac{1}{a + b} \geq \frac{1}{2 \max\{a, b\}} = \frac{1}{2} \min\{a^{-1}, b^{-1}\}. 
  $$
- What I could show so far is that, using the inequality above,
  $$
  \mathrm{trace}((A+B)^{-1}) \geq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d \min\{\lambda_i(A^{-1}), \lambda_i(B^{-1})\},
  $$
  Above, $d$ is the dimension of the matrices and $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$th largest eigenvalue. This isn't quite strong enough, though.

Comment: This holds in the case that either $A - B$ or $B - A$ is positive definite; I'm not sure about anything more general than that though

Comment: Did you try $2\times 2$-matrices?

Comment: I did, but the key was to note that it does actually hold when $A \succeq B$ or vice versa (and not otherwise, as the counter example given below shows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is no in general. As a counterexample, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & \epsilon}, \quad B = \pmatrix{\epsilon & 0\\0 & 1}, \quad \epsilon = 0.01.
$$
We have
$$
\operatorname{tr}((A + B)^{-1}) = \frac 2{1 + \epsilon} < 2 <\frac 12 \min \{\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}),\operatorname{tr}(B^{-1}))\} = \frac {1 + \epsilon^{-1}}{2} = 50.5.
$$